# How to add XML text node to an XML fragment queried by attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a system that maps data between a new schema and a legacy schema. In certain circumstances I want to update an xml field by targeting an element node based on an attribute value and performing an insert or update on the text node. I've worked out how to handle update cases but I'm having trouble with the insert, that is, cases where the text node does not exist:

The following yields the expected results:

```
DECLARE @sample xml;
SET @sample = '<CustomFields>
                <CustomField1 MapsTo="LegacyField1"></CustomField1>
                <CustomField2 MapsTo="LegacyField2"></CustomField2>
                <CustomField3 MapsTo="LegacyField3"></CustomField3>
            </CustomFields>'

SET @sample.modify('insert text{"new field value"} into (/CustomFields/CustomField2)[1]')
```

Result:

```
<CustomFields>
  <CustomField1 MapsTo="LegacyField1" />
  <CustomField2 MapsTo="LegacyField2">new field value</CustomField2>
  <CustomField3 MapsTo="LegacyField3" />
</CustomFields>
```

However, when I query for the target node using the MapsTo attribute value I get errors or bad results:

```
SET @sample.modify('insert text{"new field value"} into (/CustomFields/child::node()[@MapsTo="LegacyField2"])[1]')
```

Results in the following error: "XQuery [modify()]: The target of 'insert into' must be an element/document node, found '(element(*,xdt:untyped) | comment | processing-instruction | text) ?'"

If I grab the target node in a separate operation like so:

```
DECLARE @node XML = @sample.query('/CustomFields/child::node()[@MapsTo="LegacyField2"][1]')
```

I get the expected node:

```
<CustomField2 MapsTo="LegacyField2" />
```

But if I then run a modify:insert like so:

```
SET @node.modify('insert text{"new field value"} into (self::node())[1]')
```

I get the following unexpected result:

```
<CustomField2 MapsTo="LegacyField2" />new field value
```

What I'm looking for, of course, is:

```
<CustomField2 MapsTo="LegacyField2">new field value</CustomField2>
```

BTW: the index elements "[1]" of the last two operations appear to be redundant.

I'm likely making a simple error of syntax or conception but so far I have not been able to sort it. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
DECLARE @sample xml;
SET @sample = '<CustomFields>
                <CustomField1 MapsTo="LegacyField1"></CustomField1>
                <CustomField2 MapsTo="LegacyField2"></CustomField2>
                <CustomField3 MapsTo="LegacyField3"></CustomField3>
            </CustomFields>';

--directly into Element named CustomField2
SET @sample.modify('insert text{"new field value"} into (/CustomFields/CustomField2)[1]');

--per named "MapsTo" into LegacyField1
SET @sample.modify('insert text{"111"} into (/CustomFields/*[@MapsTo="LegacyField1"])[1]');

--per dynamically named "MapsTo" into LegacyField
DECLARE @target VARCHAR(100)='LegacyField3';
SET @sample.modify('insert text{"333"} into (/CustomFields/*[@MapsTo=sql:variable("@target")])[1]');

SELECT @sample;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much for your help. 

Any insights on the difference between '/CustomFields/child::node()[@MapsTo="LegacyField1"]' and '/CustomFields/*[@MapsTo="LegacyField1"]'?

Comment: @RickPutnam, actually not... in `.query()` they seem to work similar, but in `modify()` the `child::node()` leads to an untyped element. At the moment I haven't the time to dive into this. I'll come back later... (or maybe someone else reads this?)